# I need to set my Installation Directory

Tags: nsis

Noob question!

So so far I have written this code

```
; NSIS packaging/install script
; Docs: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Contents.html

!include LogicLib.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh

; --------------------------------
; Variables
; --------------------------------

!define dest "{{dest}}"
!define src "{{src}}"
!define name "{{name}}"
!define productName "{{productName}}"
!define author "{{author}}"
!define version "{{version}}"
!define icon "{{icon}}"
!define setupIcon "{{setupIcon}}"
!define banner "{{banner}}"

!define exec "{{productName}}.exe"

!define regkey "Software\${productName}"
!define uninstkey "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${productName}"

!define uninstaller "uninstall.exe"

; --------------------------------
; Installation
; --------------------------------

Unicode true
SetCompressor /SOLID lzma

Name "${productName}"
Icon "${setupIcon}"
OutFile "${dest}"
;InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\${productName}"
InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\WhapTk
DirText "This will install WhapTk on your computer. Choose a directory"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "${regkey}" ""

RequestExecutionLevel admin
CRCCheck on
SilentInstall normal

XPStyle on
ShowInstDetails nevershow
AutoCloseWindow false
WindowIcon off

Caption "${productName} Setup"
; Don't add sub-captions to title bar
SubCaption 3 " "
SubCaption 4 " "

Page custom welcome
Page instfiles

Var Image
Var ImageHandle

Function .onInit

    ; Extract banner image for welcome page
    InitPluginsDir
    ReserveFile "${banner}"
    File /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\banner.bmp "${banner}"

FunctionEnd

; Custom welcome page
Function welcome

    nsDialogs::Create 1018

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 185 1u 210 100% "Welcome to ${productName} version ${version} installer.$\r$\n$\r$\nClick install to begin."

    ;InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\WhapTk

    ${NSD_CreateBitmap} 0 0 170 210 ""
    Pop $Image
    ${NSD_SetImage} $Image $PLUGINSDIR\banner.bmp $ImageHandle

    SetOutPath $INSTDIR

    nsDialogs::Show

    ${NSD_FreeImage} $ImageHandle

FunctionEnd

; Installation declarations
Section "Install"

    WriteRegStr HKLM "${regkey}" "Install_Dir" "$INSTDIR"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "${uninstkey}" "DisplayName" "${productName}"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "${uninstkey}" "DisplayIcon" '"$INSTDIR\icon.ico"'
    WriteRegStr HKLM "${uninstkey}" "UninstallString" '"$INSTDIR\${uninstaller}"'
    WriteRegStr HKLM "${uninstkey}" "Publisher" "${author}"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "${uninstkey}" "DisplayVersion" "${version}"

    ; Remove all application files copied by previous installation
    RMDir /r "$INSTDIR"


    ; Include all files from /build directory
    File /r "${src}\*"

    ; Create start menu shortcut
    SetShellVarContext all
    CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${productName}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${exec}" "" "$INSTDIR\icon.ico"
    ; Create desktop shortcut
    CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\${productName}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${exec}" "" "$INSTDIR\icon.ico"

    WriteUninstaller "${uninstaller}"

SectionEnd

; --------------------------------
; Uninstaller
; --------------------------------

ShowUninstDetails nevershow

UninstallCaption "Uninstall ${productName}"
UninstallText "Don't like ${productName} anymore? Hit uninstall button."
UninstallIcon "${icon}"

UninstPage custom un.confirm un.confirmOnLeave
UninstPage instfiles

Var RemoveAppDataCheckbox
Var RemoveAppDataCheckbox_State

; Custom uninstall confirm page
Function un.confirm

    nsDialogs::Create 1018

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 1u 1u 100% 24u "If you really want to remove ${productName} from your computer press uninstall button."

    ${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 1u 35u 100% 10u "Remove also my ${productName} personal data"
    Pop $RemoveAppDataCheckbox

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd

Function un.confirmOnLeave

    ; Save checkbox state on page leave
    ${NSD_GetState} $RemoveAppDataCheckbox $RemoveAppDataCheckbox_State

FunctionEnd

; Uninstall declarations
Section "Uninstall"

    DeleteRegKey HKLM "${uninstkey}"
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "${regkey}"

    SetShellVarContext all
    Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\${productName}.lnk"
    ; Remove desktop shortcut
    Delete "$DESKTOP\${productName}.lnk"
    ; Remove whole directory from Program Files
    RMDir /r "$INSTDIR"

    ; Remove also appData directory generated by your app if user checked this option
    ${If} $RemoveAppDataCheckbox_State == ${BST_CHECKED}
        RMDir /r "$APPDATA\${productName}"
    ${EndIf}

SectionEnd
```

These are for school computers, so I want the user to be able to install the exe in the folder that they choose. (The school restricts the C drive)
I've tried

```
;InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\${productName}"
InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\WhapTk
```

But that refuses to work :( (The installer works fine it's just I can't choose my directory)
Please tell me what I did wrong!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `InstallDir` attribute initializes the `$InstDir` variable when the installer starts before any of your code is executed.

If you want to allow the end-user to change the installation directory then you would normally add a Directory page but you can also do it on a custom page or at any other point before the InstFiles page; just use something like `StrCpy $InstDir "c:\some\new\path"`.

Before you can use the `File` instruction to extract files you must use the `SetOutPath` instruction. It creates the directory and sets the destination for the `File` instructions.

A minimal installer might look something like this:

```
OutFile "MySetup.exe"
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp" ; $InstDir default value
RequestExecutionLevel Admin

Page Directory ; This page might change $InstDir
Page InstFiles

Section
SetOutPath "$InstDir" ; This basically does StrCpy $OutDir $InstDir + CreateDirectory $OutDir
File "MyApp.exe" ; This will extract as "$OutDir\MyApp.exe"
SectionEnd
```

Your example code calls `SetOutPath` in your custom welcome page and at that point `$InstDir` just has the value from `InstallDir` and you never call `SetOutPath` again after that.

Comment: Ok! So that worked but one problem... When I added it to my code, what ever directory I set it to was automatically erased..(Gave me quite a scare when I set it to my Program Files XD) Is there anyway for it to make a new folder in the directory the User specifies and then install it from there?

Comment: You have RMDir /R somewhere in your code. Most installers only deletes stuff in the uninstaller. It is probably a good idea for you to add "MessageBox MB_OK $InstDir" a couple of places in your code and watch as the path changes at certain points in the installer (One in .onInit, one in the first section etc.).

Comment: So if I remove the code that removes all the files in the directory, will it automatically add a folder (which in my case is "WhapTk" which will place the program files in there?

Comment: They are not related, I only mentioned RMDir because you said you had a problem with things getting deleted. SetOutPath will create the directory tree if it does not exist and files will be extracted to this location...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an additional [`Page`](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/Page.md) for the selection dialog:

```
Page directory
Page instfiles
```

Keep in mind that the order of declaring these pages is important, usually `instfiles` goes last.

Comment: Ok thanks! I've gotten the "Choose directory" page! But unfortunately the place I choose for it to install does not get the file. It downloads to Program Files no matter what I do!

Comment: Add `SetOutPath $INSTDIR` before your `File` instruction